# How to update multiple models in one fucntion inside controller - Laravel vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, controller

I am trying to update multiple models that related to each other with PK and FK.

I tried to update the first model "matter_dispute" and successfully updated so I repeated the same thing to update the other model "matter_dispute_c" but it didn't affect anything.

Here is the update function in controller:

```php
public function update(Request $request, matter_dispute $matter_dispute, matter_dispute_b $matter_dispute_b, matter_dispute_c $matter_dispute_c)
{
    $request->validate([
        'pic_1'=>'required',
        'pic_2'=>'required',

        'remarks'=>'required',
        'file_ref_no'=>'required',
    ]);

    $postData = [
        'pic_1' => $request->pic_1,
        'pic_2' => $request->pic_2,
    ];

    $postData2 = [
        'remarks' => $request->remarks,
        'file_ref_no' => $request->file_ref_no,
    ];

    $matter_dispute->update($postData);
    $matter_dispute_c->update($postData2);
}
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach to do it, is it better if i use query for it?

Because the way I am getting data as showing below:

```php
$matter_dispute_all_tables = DB::table('matter_disputes')
    ->join('matter_dispute_bs', 'matter_disputes.id', '=', 'matter_dispute_bs.matter_disputes_id')
    ->join('matter_dispute_cs', 'matter_disputes.id', '=', 'matter_dispute_cs.matter_disputes_id')
    ->select('matter_disputes.*', 'matter_dispute_bs.*', 'matter_dispute_cs.*')
    ->get()
;

return response()->json($matter_dispute_all_tables);
```

So which approach is better and how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

I used Laravel Eloquent as showing below:

```
DB::table('matter_disputes')
    ->join('matter_dispute_bs', 'matter_disputes.id', '=', 'matter_dispute_bs.matter_disputes_id')
    ->join('matter_dispute_cs', 'matter_disputes.id', '=', 'matter_dispute_cs.matter_disputes_id')
    ->where('matter_disputes.id',$matter_dispute->id)
    ->update([
        'pic_1' => $request->pic_1,
        'pic_2' => $request->pic_2,
        'remarks' => $request->remarks,
        'file_ref_no' => $request->file_ref_no,
    ]);
```